# how to get rows as columns with count for every user

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the user_id's and events that happened to them, I want to get each event name as a column with the count for every user[data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BLQL.png)
I have data is like

```
-------------------
user_id|event_name
--------------------
1233445|photo_upload_error
2636357|user_engagement
```

---

I want to get it as

```
------------------------------------------------------
user_id|photo_upload_error|user_engagement|screen_view
-----------------------------------------------------
1233445|        5         |      1        |       1
6534734|        0         |      3        |       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the columns you want (as in your sample results), you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select user_pseudo_id,
       countif(event_name = 'photo_upload_error') as photo_upload_error,
       countif(event_name = 'user_engagement') as user_engagement,
       countif(event_name = 'screen_view') as screen_view
from t
group by 1;
```

You may want to filter down to users that have only these columns.  I would suggest adding:

```
where event_name in ('photo_upload_error', 'user_engagement', 'screen_view')
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon , it worked!! How can I get the rows only which having values?